# Why does Google remove special characters from search?

Tags: search, google, special-characters

It's worth noting not all special characters are removed, for example **C#** and **C++** (programming languages) return results, **$** returns results, etc.

However, I tried searching for a code segment that I use in ASP.Net **"<%#"** and it returned no results. I tried searching **"<%# in ASP"** and it returned the same results it would have if I had searched just **"in ASP"**. So it was clearly ignoring special characters.

I searched around and only found this thread on the topic 
[Search including special characters and other normally ignored symbols/words](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/s-HO7oGAM0E) where the only reasoning is at a 404'd link. It does explain however that they include spcecial charcters that are associated with "popular terms". That link also shows that many users hate this experience as it leads to results they didn't want.

I assume implementation isn't the issue as it is Google, the most used (and probably best funded) search engine out there. So what is the reasoning behind leaving those searches out? Why include them when only when used in "popular terms"? What benefit would that have to a user?

Comment: When you say implementation, are you referring to thwarting potential hackers who are attempting to inject code into the search input?

Comment: That being the main one yes, Google should have no problem sanitizing input before running it through the search algorithm.

Comment: Things have changed: http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/02/google-search-improves-searching-special-characters-programming-languages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it largely has something to do with the fact that those special operators are used for specific Google query purposes, and take precedence over code notation. From Google's own [documentation](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?vid=1-635770001269228919-1847463861):

[image: google search operator table]

Also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters) offers a variety of workarounds to this issue, in case you were curious.

Comment: Therefore google should recognize he does not want that <% hashtag on twitter and be more intuitive,google should know better